# Deriving the round metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider $\mathbb{S}^2$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Given that $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ has the standard Riemannian metric $g$, I want to derive a local expression or the metric tensor for the round metric $\mathring{g}$ on $\mathbb{S}^2$.

This is given by $\mathring{g}=\iota^*g$ so for $u,v \in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$ one has $$\mathring{g}(u,v)=g_{\iota(p)}(d\iota_p(u),d\iota_p(v)).$$

Also in coordiantes we can express $$g=\sum g_{ij}dx^i \otimes dx^j$$ where $g_{ij}=g_p(\partial/\partial x^i,\partial/\partial x^j)$ so the pullback would result in $$\mathring{g}=\sum (\iota^*g)_{ij} dx^i \otimes dx^j.$$ To find the local expression I need to compute $$(\iota^*g)_{ij}$$ but what is this expression? I don't know how to compute it. Do I need to parameterize $\mathbb{S}^2$ or can I do this without it?

Comment: Where does the expression for $\dot{g}$ in the third equation come from? I do not think that it is a valid formula for the coordinate expression of the pullback of a covariant tensor field. After all $dx^i$ and $dx^j$ are not even covector fields on $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula for the pull-back is not right.
Pulling-back a tensor is a linear operation.
Moreover, as mentioned in @jd27's comment, $dx^i$ are not well-defined on $S^2$ as it stands.

Formally, the pull-back of $g$ by $\iota$ should read
\begin{align}
\iota^*g &= \iota^*\left( \sum_{i,j=1}^3g_{ij} dx^i\otimes dx^j \right) \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^3 \iota^*\left(g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j \right) \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^3 (g_{ij}\circ \iota)\, \iota^*( dx^i \otimes dx^j) \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^3 (g_{ij}\circ \iota)\, \iota^*(dx^i) \otimes \iota^*(dx^j) \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^3 (g_{ij}\circ \iota)\, d(x^i\circ \iota) \otimes d(x^j\circ \iota).
\end{align}

But then, this is not an expression of the round metric in coordinates for the sphere.
Indeed, $\{x^1\circ \iota, x^2\circ \iota,x^3\circ \iota\}$ is **not** a coordinate patch on the sphere, for the simple reason that the sphere is two dimensional, so any coordinate patch should have only two coordinate functions.

To derive a coordinate expression of the sphere, you need to first consider a coordinate patch $\{y^1,y^2\}$ on $S^2$ and then look at $\iota^*g$ in these coordinates.
There are as many expressions as coordinate patches: an infinite number of them.
Usually, one would use polar coordinates or stereographical ones.

Comment: Should it not be $g_{ij} \circ \iota$ instead of just $g_{ij}$ (after the second $=$)? Although i guess in this case that is kind of trivial.

Comment: @jd27 Rigorously speaking, you are perfectly right. I edited the answer, thanks

Comment: (+1) Re: coordinates, "... or projection to a diameter (because Archimedes' theorem)." :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try to see if I understood what you meant. So to derive the expression for the sphere we first need charts or local coordinates for it before we can do anything? I think I made a misconception here by assuming that we have some kinda induced charts from $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we parameterize the sphere with $(\theta,\varphi) \mapsto (\sin\theta \cos\varphi, \sin\theta\sin\varphi, \cos\theta)$ the equation you gave would give something like

Comment: $$\begin{align*}\mathring{g} &= d(\sin\theta\cos\varphi) \otimes d(\sin\theta\cos\varphi) + d(\sin\theta\sin\varphi) \otimes d(\sin\theta\sin\varphi) + d(\cos\theta) \otimes d(\cos\theta) \\
&= (\cos\theta\cos\varphi d\theta -\sin\theta\sin\varphi d\varphi) \otimes(\cos\theta\cos\varphi d\theta -\sin\theta\sin\varphi d\varphi) + (\cos\theta\sin\varphi d\theta + \sin\theta\cos\varphi d\varphi) \otimes (\cos\theta\sin\varphi d\theta + \sin\theta\cos\varphi d\varphi)\end{align*}$$

Comment: which possibly simplifies a lot.

Comment: @Michele  Under polar coordinates  $(\theta,\varphi)$, the metric of $S^2$ is  $g=\left(
\begin{array}{1}
1  &0  \\
0  &\sin^2\theta
\end{array}
\right)$.

Comment: @Michele It's not the chart that is induced from $\Bbb R^3$, it's the metric. What you did makes perfect sense, but notice that you used a parametrization of the sphere, i.e, a chart of the sphere!